# Apollo server express return type with generic

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo

## Environment

- [apollo-server-express](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server#readme)
- typescript
- nodejs

## Question

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-server-express';

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Result<T> {
    success: bool
    result: T?
    message: String 
  }
  type Query {
    name: String!
  }
  type Mutation {
    reset(team: Int?)
    editName(name: String): String!
  }
`
export default typeDefs;
```

I want to use Result type for generic purpose like that `type Result<T>`

Is this possible in apollo graphql?

Check Please!

Comment: What your writing in `typeDefs` is a different language to TypeScript. The different language is GraphQL that doesn't support generics.

Comment: @DanStarns OK thanks!